# APK will not install on android device after intune wrapping?

Tags: android, intune, apksigner

Small question for all y'all android people! I have built a little test app, which I have signed with a self-signed certificate.

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop> apksigner verify --print-certs '.\temp.apk'
Signer #1 certificate DN: CN=Self Signed, OU=TEMP, O=meInc, L=NY, ST=N, C=US
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: 5813305afb51a0c0dd
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 5813305afb51a0c0dd
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: 5813305afb51a0c0dd
WARNING: META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/app-metadata.properties not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
```

I can install the self-signed APK on the device and it works fine.

At this point, I have the signed app...

with steps:

1. build
2. sign

However, when I try to intune wrap the apk, the output says everything is fine...

```
Application wrapping in progress. App Wrapping Tool Version: 1.0.4191.6
[main manifest:11] Manifest has more than one /manifest/uses-permission[@name=android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE] element.
The package name for this app is 'com.temp.test'. If you need to specify the package name during deployment, please use this one.
**The application was successfully wrapped.**
Please zipalign and sign the application before use.
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop>
```

But, when I try to install the apk on the actual android device, it gives me an error... "APP not installed as package appears to be invalid."

Why is that?

I mean all I did was ..

1. build
2. sign
3. intune wrap

Has anyone come across this before?